# Platform Invoke error attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pinvoke

I am getting am error when I am trying to use platform invoke example where I am trying to change the Lower and Upper case of string.

Here is what I got so far:

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "CharLowerBuffA",
     ExactSpelling = false,
     CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
     SetLastError = true
      )]
    public static extern string CharLower(string lpsz);

    [DllImport("User32.dll",
     EntryPoint = "CharUpperBuffA",
     ExactSpelling = false,
     CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
     SetLastError = true
      )]
    public static extern string CharUpper(string lpsz);     

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string l = "teSarf";

        string ChangeToLower = CharLower(l.ToLower());
        string ChangeToUpper = CharUpper(l.ToUpper());
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", ChangeToLower);
        Console.ReadLine();   
    }
}
```

I am not sure where I am going wrong with this but I think it is to do with the **EntryPoint**.

I have to use **Unicode** and **CharLowerBuffW** didn't work either.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647468(v=vs.85).aspx) indicates that `CharLowerBuffA` is the ANSI variant of that method, but you are specifying Unicode.

Try either using ANSI - by specifying `CharSet = CharSet.Ansi` - or if you need Unicode, use `CharLowerBuffW` and `CharUpperBuffW`.

As well, the method takes two parameters. You don't have the second one. So try this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll", EntryPoint = "CharLowerBuffW",
 ExactSpelling = false,
 CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
 SetLastError = true
  )]
public static extern string CharLower(string lpsz, int cchLength);

[DllImport("User32.dll",
 EntryPoint = "CharUpperBuffW",
 ExactSpelling = false,
 CharSet = CharSet.Unicode,
 SetLastError = true
  )]
public static extern string CharUpper(string lpsz, int cchLength);
```

And call it like this:

```
string ChangeToLower = CharLower(l, l.Length);
```

If that still doesn't work, then try using character arrays, like NatarajC mentioned.

Comment: CharUpperBuffW got the same result and I do need unicode

Comment: I also noticed that you're missing the length parameter. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Same result means, it still giving same error, try using string.ToCharArray() while calling the method, change the signature to char array.